# Need help on how to structure my database (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, database-design

[image: tables]

Everything that isn't labeled "calc" or "finalvalue" is raw data that I will be manipulating.

I finally know enough SQL to be able to create the necessary tables and perform the needed calculations.  However, I just wanted to verify that there is no simpler way to do this, something that would involve fewer tables.

Would it be better to create views instead of actually altering the tables and inserting calculated columns?  I don't actually care about the calculated columns in Table1 and Table2 after I have the final data in Table3.  SQL Server 2008.

I should also note that I will be receiving new raw data for Table1 and Table2 every day, and that I plan on appending these records and then appending my new Final Values to Table3 with a date field.

Comment: Anytime you're considering adding tables/columns dynamically to SQL, you're 100% doing it wrong (Well, perhaps 99.9%, but still!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878

You never want to store calculations directly in a table, the calculations will be done by the queries that generate your data.  Table 3 is actually the results of a simple query.

From what you have above, I would say you have at least the following three tables:

Customers - contains basic customer data, one row per customer, and some kind of ID that you generate (probably an integer identity column is best, but can be anything you choose).

Produce (or Products, if you have more than fruit and vegetables) - one row per product containing product information, some kind of ID that you generate (again, integer identity is the best).

Sales - one row per transaction

Here's where things get a little tricky.  You could have Sales and SalesItems where sales has a unique row for each transaction and SalesItems contains one row for each product that was purchased in the transaction, but for a really simple system as you appear to have above, you could just get away with a Sales table that has ProductID and CustomerID along with quantity and whatever else you want to store.

EDIT: It's a safe bet that a simple system will one day grow into a complicated system, so if I were designing the database I would probably go with separate tables for Sales and SalesItems to make the database more flexible and able to scale better.

Comment: Thank you.  I think this makes a lot of sense.  In the end, I care most about tracking performance by group, like how "fruit" has done compared to "vegetables".  The breakdown of customer by customer isn't the main goal.

Comment: Yeah I hear you, I've just been to so many customers that stood up a database to solve one tiny problem and before they knew it it grew into their most important application.  At some point in the future you never know if you might become interested in which customers buy the most fruit vs. vegetables or something like that.  It's always nice to plan the design out in a way that allows it to expand to other requirements in the future.

Comment: When you say you never want to directly store calculated data in a table, do you mean to that I should create a separate table for such data, or that there is some way to generate the values in Table3 without ever storing the calculated columns in Table1 & Table2?

Comment: You never need to store the calculated columns, you only store the raw data and you do the calculations in a query.  I don't know what your calculations are, but let's say they are Total, Minimum and Maximum.  In your query you would do something like: SELECT Customer, Produce, sum(quantity), min(quantity), max(quantity) FROM sales GROUP BY Customer, Produce

Comment: Yeah, I guess that's what I'm doing.  All of the above calculated columns are the results of queries that perform calculations.